# Sorting multiple dictionary dimensions at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the following form:

```
{
    "b":{
          "ba": {
                 "Score":3,
                 "N":500
                },
          "aa": {
                 "Score": 10,
                 "N":300
                },
        },
    "a":{
         "xy": {
                 "Score":199,
                 "N":7
               },
         "zz": {
                 "Score":222,
                 "N":55
               },
         }
}
```

I want the first dimension to be sorted alphabetically, but the second to be sorted by `Score`, such that when sorted it would look like:

```
{
    "a":{
         "zz": {
                 "Score":222,
                 "N":55
               },
         "xy": {
                 "Score":199,
                 "N":7
               }
         },
    "b":{
          "aa": {
                 "Score": 10,
                 "N":300
                },
          "ba": {
                 "Score":3,
                 "N":500
                }
        }
}
```

I have searched for an answer to this for a while, but I have only found how to sort a single dimension in a dictionary. What would be the best pythonic way to go about doing this?

After sorting I need to dump it to a file which I was planning on using the `json` module for. So doing something like:

```
with open("out.json", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(my_dict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Just a minor obstacle: dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: @MSeifert I know dictionaries are unordered when stored in Python, but I need to output it sorted (as stated) into a json file, as per my edit.

Comment: So using an `OrderedDict` would be fine?

Comment: building an ordereddict containing other ordereddicts and dump them as json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an appropriate [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) using eg:

```
ordered = OrderedDict(
    [(k, OrderedDict(
        sorted(v.items(), key=lambda pair: -pair[1]["Score"]))) 
     for k, v in sorted(data.items())])
```

Now dump it to json

```
>>> print(json.dumps(ordered, indent=2))
{
  "a": {
    "zz": {
      "Score": 222, 
      "N": 55
    }, 
    "xy": {
      "Score": 199, 
      "N": 7
    }
  }, 
  "b": {
    "aa": {
      "Score": 10, 
      "N": 300
    }, 
    "ba": {
      "Score": 3, 
      "N": 500
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** You could use `reverse=True` inside the inner sort instead of negating the score, depends how you feel ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) because plain dictionaries are unordered so putting the sorted dict in another plain dict would throw away the order again.

Then first sort the outer keys and then sort the inner dictionaries in-place:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {"b":{"ba": {"Score":3, "N":500},
          "aa": {"Score": 10, "N":300},},
    "a":{"xy": {"Score":199, "N":7},
         "zz": {"Score":222, "N":55},}}

d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))  # sorts the outer keys
for k, v in d.items():
    # sort the inner keys by score
    d[k] = OrderedDict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Score'], reverse=True))
```

Afterwards `d` looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([('a',
              OrderedDict([('zz', {'N': 55, 'Score': 222}),
                           ('xy', {'N': 7, 'Score': 199})])),
             ('b',
              OrderedDict([('aa', {'N': 300, 'Score': 10}),
                           ('ba', {'N': 500, 'Score': 3})]))])
```